# getClass().getResource() in static context

Tags: java, url, static, getresource

I'm trying to get a resource (image.png, in the same package as this code) from a static method using this code:

```
import java.net.*;

public class StaticResource {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        URL u = StaticResource.class.getClass().getResource("image.png");
        System.out.println(u);
    }

}
```

The output is just 'null'

I've also tried `StaticResource.class.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("image.png");`
, it throws a `NullPointerException`

I've seen other solutions where this works, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What error are you getting?  Are you sure you have the image in the classpath?

Comment: ClassName.class is exactly the same as SomeClassReference.getClass().  You are getting the class of the StaticResource class.

Comment: @jgitter it either outputs null or throws a NullPointerException

Comment: Don't use in this way. Why are using `getClassLoader()`? Simply use `StaticResource.class.getResource("image.png")`

Comment: Always try to place the resources outside the JAVA code to make it more manageable and reusable by other package's class.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Remove the ".getClass()" part.
Just use

```
URL u = StaticResource.class.getResource("image.png");
```

Comment: +1 `X.class.getClass()` is always going to be the `Class` class as all Classes have a type of `Class`  As this is loaded by the boot loader, it almost never has the resource you want. ;)

Answer (score 0):

> Always try to place the resources outside the JAVA code to make it more manageable and reusable by other package's class.

You can try any one

```
// Read from same package 
URL url = StaticResource.class.getResource("c.png");

// Read from same package 
InputStream in = StaticResource.class.getResourceAsStream("c.png");

// Read from absolute path
File file = new File("E:/SOFTWARE/TrainPIS/res/drawable/c.png");

// Read from images folder parallel to src in your project
File file = new File("images/c.jpg");

// Read from src/images folder
URL url = StaticResource.class.getResource("/images/c.png")

// Read from src/images folder
InputStream in = StaticResource.class.getResourceAsStream("/images/c.png")
```

Comment: I don't get the last 3 - they seem to make assumptions on the structure of some project, which may (or rather may not) apply to someone else's setup.

Comment: I want to try to keep resources outside the packages.

Comment: just create the images folder to place all the images inside this folder.